# Adding Request Headers to Azure Application Insights Events in Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights, hapi.js

The Azure Application Insights Node module collects HTTP requests by default, however, these events don't seem to include the requests' headers.

How should I best include the headers in these events?

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom Telemetry Processor to do this 
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/44330896f58d4e6c2b6c4fec821430f7e1067138/README.md#preprocess-data-with-telemetry-processors

Here's an example:

```
const logHTTPheaders = (envelope, context) => {
  const httpRequest = context['http.ServerRequest'];
  if (httpRequest && appInsights.Contracts.domainSupportsProperties(envelope.data.baseData)) {
    _.forOwn(httpRequest.headers, (headerValue, headerName) => {
      _.set(envelope, `data.baseData.properties.[header-${headerName}]`, headerValue);
    });
  }
  return true;
};

// Telemetry processor to record HTTP request header
appInsights.defaultClient.addTelemetryProcessor(logHTTPheaders);
```